# CSS: Container is not aligned correctly in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive-design

I have designed a banner for a website but there is an issue in the container placement on Safari browser (All other browsers are working fine).

This is my intended style for the banner, the Prime Day text should be on the right as in the following image:
[image]

However in Safari, it is displaying like this:

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this? What could possibly be causing this behavior?

Any sort of pointers will be very helpful.

```css
element.style {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0021/4889/2732/files/main_desk_2x_3_dc552044-0d7b-48c0-aaa1-491a018b88d4.jpg?v=1657052323);
  color: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  min-height: fit-content;
  height: 540px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 100% center;
}

.styles_banner__2zleP {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100vw;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  font-family: "AvenirNextLTPro";
}

.styles_layout--justifyRight__CDYKz {
  justify-content: right;
}

.styles_layout__QX3op {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 1170px;
}

.styles_banner__link__nxcMI {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

element.style {
  width: 480px;
}

.styles_justifyCenter__e_d5I,
.styles_justifyCenter__e_d5I .styles_content__fRIh1,
.styles_justifyCenter__e_d5I .styles_content__fRIh1>* {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.styles_content__fRIh1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<section class="styles_banner__2zleP" data-testid="sale-banner" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0021/4889/2732/files/main_desk_2x_3_dc552044-0d7b-48c0-aaa1-491a018b88d4.jpg?v=1657052323&quot;); color: rgb(41, 41, 41); min-height: fit-content; height: 540px; background-size: cover; background-position: 100% center;">
  <a class="styles_layout__QX3op styles_banner__link__nxcMI styles_layout--justifyRight__CDYKz styles_layout--alignCenter__XqCw6" href="/collections/prime-day-sale">
    <div class="styles_content__fRIh1 styles_justifyCenter__e_d5I" style="width: 480px;"><img alt="" decoding="async" class="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/" srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_180/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 180w,https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_360/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 360w,https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_720/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 720w,https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_900/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 900w,https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_1080/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 1080w,https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_1200/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 1200w,https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_1920/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 1920w,https://res.cloudinary.com/shogun-frontend/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,c_limit,w_2048/https://f.shgcdn.com/2dacaf9b-2222-45de-a76f-f470df139754/ 2048w"
        loading="lazy">
      <p>Get affordable <strong>SupportiveWear</strong></p>
      <p> essentials at Prime Day deals!</p><button class="css-1276jxf" type="button" data-testid="sale-banner-button">SHOP THE SALE</button>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Try `justify-content: start;` (or end) instead of right ?

Comment: Both didn't work unfortunately but justify-content: flex-end; seemed to have worked. Can you explain what could be happening as it is working fine in other borwsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `justify-content: flex-start;` or `justify-content: flex-end;`.

While `left` and `right` are part of the spec, some browser don't support those values for `justify-content`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#browser_compatibility.